# Grep lines only if containing 2 specific strings

Tags: shell, perl, awk, grep

Is it possible to `grep` lines only if containing 2 specific strings in it?

I have logs like this and I would like to grep only lines containing strings "13/Dec/2022:11" **AND** "GET /fr/test"

```
access.log:site.ch 111.222.333.444 - - [13/Dec/2022:11:40:00 +0100] "GET /fr/test HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grep twice:

```
| grep "13/Dec/2022:11" | grep "GET /fr/test"
```

Or combined with zgrep

```
zgrep "13/Dec/2022:11" * | grep "GET /fr/test"
```

Comment: The operator | is OR not AND isn't it ? I need AND operator

Comment: @sdespont: Try it, you will be surprised.

Comment: I tried, but the command returns lines containing one of the two strings ?! I have played `zgrep "13/Dec/2022:11" | zgrep "GET /fr/test" *`

Comment: @sdespont: `zgrep` is for compressed data and outputs non compressed data. Your second `zgrep` is out of place here.

Comment: @sdespont `|` is a pipe character. I suggest reading about shell piping. I use `awk` every day, but I prefer grepping this way, because it's super easy and still somewhat flexible. `grep a | grep -i b | grep -v c` prints lines with a, b or B and without c. This is always a 2-second no-brainer and works on first try.

Comment: @steffen great ! And is it possible to combine this with zgrep in order to look in compressed files?

Comment: @sdespont Of course. Reading from files: `grep <pattern> <file> | grep <pattern> | grep <pattern>`. The first grep can be replaced by zgrep if the file is compressed. (zgrep works for uncompressed data es well, so all greps can be replaced, but it's always a good idea to write self-documenting code.)

Comment: @sdespont So `zgrep <pattern1> <pattern2> file | grep <pattern3> ` would grep all lines from a (possibly compressed) file that contain (pattern1 OR pattern2) AND pattern3.

Comment: @steffen I have tested the suggestion above, works fine and more simple than a regex. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this, just one `awk`:

```
awk '/13\/Dec\/2022:11/ && /GET \/fr\/test/' file
```

or one `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if m|13/Dec/2022:11| and m|GET /fr/test|' file
```

or one `sed`:

```
sed -n '/13\/Dec\/2022:11/,/GET \/fr\/test/p' file
```

or with one `zgrep` or `grep`:

```
zgrep -E '13/Dec/2022:11.*?GET /fr/test' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much, in fact I have to use zgrep to look into compressed files, is there one of your answer permitting to do that?

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep and 2 strings:

```
grep -E 'string1.*string2|string2.*string1' file
```

Comment: Good idea, I don't need this complexity because I know the order of the strings in the file.